# Using a single transistor & capacitor (DRAM) vs a flip-flop(SRAM) to store a single bit of data

Tags: transistors, capacitor, flipflop, sram, dram

I'm a beginner trying to understand the working of SRAM and DRAM.

According to [sources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_random-access_memory),  DRAMs use a single transistor along with a capacitor(1T1C) to store a single bit, where the capacitor holds the charge that denotes the state (1 or 0) of the particular memory cell(and of-course the capacitor needs to be refreshed periodically to overcome leakage).

Now in case of an SRAM, how does a flip-flop(assuming transistor only circuit) retain its state (1 or 0) after the input signal is cut-off?

Please correct me if my understanding of DRAM/SRAM is wrong.

Comment: Try googling flip-flop circuit https://www.google.ca/search?dcr=0&biw=1680&bih=972&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=LoM6WoncGZOzjwT5goO4DA&q=flip-flop+circuit&oq=flip-flop+circuit&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0j0i30k1l6j0i5i30k1l3.3064.4237.0.4639.8.8.0.0.0.0.123.785.6j2.8.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.8.778...0i67k1.0.gJ8bEnVzDBw#imgrc=qVnt9opFuFl3sM:&spf=1513784154434

Comment: Flipflop is a bi-stable circuit.

Comment: "..how does a flip-flop in an SRAM.." An SRAM does **not** use FFs for storing data. It uses six CMOS gates. Look up SRAM on WIKI!

Comment: @user3535598 And the first sentence on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_random-access_memory) says "Static random-access memory (static RAM or SRAM) is a type of semiconductor memory that uses bistable latching circuitry (flip-flop) to store each bit"

Comment: @user3535598 "flip flop" could mean any of several different circuits.  What they all have in common is that the circuit will stay in either one of two stable states until something causes it to change to the other state.  You can build a flip flop out of digital logic gates (including CMOS gates).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because lack of research effort.

Comment: @user3535598, I thought it used 6 transistors, not 6 gates.

Comment: [This](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/200118/how-does-a-flip-flop-circuit-keep-it-state?rq=1) was my original query. Found this question already answered **after** posting my question :-(

Comment: @winny I don't believe that's actually a reason to close a question here. The goal of stack exchange is to become the repository of all great info. Regardless of how basic a question is, I believe stack exchange would love to be the first google hit.

Comment: @horta I can revert it to duplicate of https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/200118/how-does-a-flip-flop-circuit-keep-it-state if you want.

Comment: Basically a duplicate of [How does a flip-flop circuit keep it state?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/200118/how-does-a-flip-flop-circuit-keep-it-state)

Comment: @Tony M. Yes, that is what I mean six CMOS transistors. And I'll just have to agree to disagree on calling a set of back-to-back inverters a FF. If you use that definition then a D-register has two FFs.

Comment: @user3535598, gates are made out of several transistors. Transistors are made out of one. It doesn't matter if we agree or not though, they're quite distinct nouns in electronics. The definitions have been done for us so it's no problem.

Comment: @winny That's probably a good idea. Linked/duplicated questions are good to have on the site too to help others uncover the data they're after.

Comment: @Tony M. I completely agree. I think there is a misunderstanding: When I wrote 'agree to disagree' that was about the term Flip-Flop with james.

Comment: @user3535598, oh good, all's well then and a very Merry Christmas to you :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's two inverters that use positive feedback to retain a bit. Once the bit is setup and there remains power, the two inverters will forever be stuck in that same state. To change the bit, you have to override the internal positive feedback of the system. You would do that through M5 and M6.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

An SRAM cell is actually two crossed feedback loops. Look at its schematic and you will immediately see it.
As long as the SRAM has power, the loops are running and maintain their state, even without any input signal.